# Third party DLL not working in Web Application, but working Windows Forms application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, dll, dllimport, winforms-interop

Im faching a strange issue with a DLL. We are moving Windows Forms app to a web app. But a dll which is working in Windows Forms not working in web application. our environment is ASP.NET 4.5

I tried switching 32 and 64 CPU. But in Web application, we are getting an error when using the function from the DLL. The DLL is referencing into the app without any issue. And also we are getting list of all functions in it. But when executing, it triggers an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error in web app is like "could not find the file specified". But the same code is working fine in windows app (Fresh new windows forms app). I only refer the dll in windows app and copy the code to it and it worked. But in web app triggered that error.

Comment: You need check that your dll is in "bin" folder where Web app is executed